# Connection between the Modulation Transfer Function (MTF) and Line Spread Function (LSF) in "Hecht - Optics, 5th ed"

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, imaging, image-processing

I try to understand the derivation of the connection of the MTF and the LSF and found a derivation in the Book "Optics" by Eugene Hecht (5th edition), chapter 11, section 11.3.6.
However, there is a small part of the proof, that is "left as an excersize for the reader" and I have some problems with this.
Here is short recap that everybody without the book at hand should be able to follow along:

An image under the condition of space invariance and incoherence can be expressed by a convolution of the object irradiance and the LSF:
$$I_i(Y,Z) = I_0(y,z)\circledast S(y,z)$$

Only S(y,z) depends on the imaging system. The same statement in spatial frequency domain:
$$F(I_i(Y,Z)) = F(I_0(y,z))F(S(y,z))$$
So it is clear that $F(S(y,z))$ is an optical transfer function OTF, because it transfers the spectrum of the object irradiance to the spectrum of the image irradiance. We will call it $T(y,z) = F(S(y,z))$. This is an unnormalized OTF. It has a modulus and a phase.
How does the irradiance of the object look like? For simplicity, let's look at 1D:
$$I_0(z) = 1+ a \cos(k_z z + \epsilon) $$
Remember that $f \circledast h = h \circledast f$ because $I_i(Z) = S(Z) \circledast I_0(Z)$ is more convenient.
Performing the convolution gives
y$$ I_i(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(1+ a \cos(k_z (Z-z) + \epsilon)\right) S(z) dz $$
Expanding the cosine
$$ I_i(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(z) dz + a \cos(k_z Z + \epsilon) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}cos(k_Z z) S(z) dz + a \sin(k_z Z + \epsilon) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}sin(k_Z z) S(z) dz $$
The integrals are Fourier cosine and sine transforms
$$ I_i(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(z) dz + a \cos(k_z Z + \epsilon) F_c(S(z)) + a \sin(k_z Z + \epsilon) F_s(S(z)) $$
Recall the complex Fourier transform:
$F(f(z)) = F_c(f(z)) + i F_s(f(z))$
We define the following:
$F(S(s)) = M(k_z)e^{i\Phi(k_z)}$
It can now be shown* that
$$ I_i(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(z) dz + a M(k_z) \cos(k_z Z + \epsilon - \Phi(k_z))$$
Compare this function to
$$I_0(z) = 1+ a \cos(k_z z + \epsilon) $$
They have the same form, but the former is modulated!
If line-spread function is symmetrical, e.g. $F_s(S(z)) = 0$ it follows that $M(k_z)=F_c(S(z))$, then there is no phase shift $\Phi(k_z)$.

**However**, if I try to do the part with "it can now be shown that" I find:

let's define $\phi = \phi(z)=k_z Z + \epsilon, F_c(S(z)) = F_c, F_s(S(z))=F_s$
$$ a \cos(k_z Z + \epsilon) F_c(S(z)) + a \sin(k_z Z + \epsilon) F_s(S(z)) = a F_c 1/2 \left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right) + a F_s 1/2i \left(e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}\right) $$
Now use $F_c = M e^{i\Phi}-iF_s$:
$$ (M e^{i-\Phi}-iF_s) 1/2 \left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right) +  F_s 1/2i \left(e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}\right)= 1/2 (M e^{i(\phi+\Phi)}+M e^{i(-\phi+\Phi)}) - i/2 F_s e^{i\phi} - i/2 F_s e^{-i\phi} + 1/2i F_s e^{i\phi} - 1/2iF_s e^{-i\phi} = M cos(phi-\Phi)-iF_s e^{i\phi}$$
The last term does not appear in the book...
Did I do something wrong?